# Notification Listener Service not started when running in debug mode

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

I am building an app using the NotificationListenerService. But always when I run the app in debug mode the Service is not started. I reduced my code to the following:

My Acticity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val intent = Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS")
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        val isServiceRunning = isMyServiceRunning(NLService::class.java)
        Log.i("MainActivity", "service running: " + isServiceRunning)

    }

    private fun isMyServiceRunning(serviceClass: Class<*>): Boolean {
        val manager = getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
        for (service in manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.name == service.service.className) {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

The Service:

```
class NLService : NotificationListenerService() {

    private val TAG: String? = "NLService"

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        Log.i(TAG, "onBind()")
        return super.onBind(intent)
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate()")
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onNotificationPosted(sbn: StatusBarNotification?) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onNotificationPosted() sbn: $sbn")
        super.onNotificationPosted(sbn)
    }
}
```

Of course I added this in manifest:

```
<service
    android:name=".NLService"
    android:label="MyNLService"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
    </intent-filter>

</service>
```

When starting the app in debug mode then I always get the log output `service running: false` in `onResume`. The value is true when starting normally, without debug. What is going wrong and how to fix that?

Comment: This is likely a timing problem. Android starts your `NotificationListenerService` and you may not be giving it enough time.

Comment: What do you mean by not giving it enough time? Could you describe a bit more in detail? Do you think I maybe do to fast startup in onListenerConnected()? So should I initialize things in that method with a postDelayed? Or do you think I shall call requestRebind() before onListenerConnected() every time? Calling requestRebind() for now is my fallback for re-connecting the service as soon as I detected that the service is not running.

Comment: You should post more code or try to determine why the `Service` is crashing. You've not given enough information to help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, finally I don't have a complete solution but a kind of improvement which is close to a working solution.

So what are actually the technical problems in **my original app code**? And how did I solve them?

1. I made some initialization in `NLService` class' `onConnect()` method. I moved all this initialization to `onListenerConnected()`, adding a `handler.postDelayed(runnable, 500);`.
2. I created an object of a class (Let's call it `MyHandlerClass`) within the `NLService` class and passed a reference to the Service into it. This is not a good solution because Android [documentation says something about many methods](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html#getActiveNotifications(java.lang.String[])) within the `NotificationListenerService`:

   > The service should wait for the onListenerConnected() event before performing this operation.

So in `MyHandlerClass` I called a `nlService.getActiveNotifications()`. This call was made **maybe** before Android called `NLService`s' `onListenerConnected`. So I made wrappers for methods inside `NLService`, like e.g.:

```
fun getActiveNotifications(): Array<StatusBarNotification>?
{
    return if (isConnected)
    {
        super.getActiveNotifications()
    }
    else
    {
        null
    }
}
```

And I toggled my boolean variable `isConnected` within `onListenerConnected()`and `onListenerDisconnected()`

Now the service still crashes when running app in debug mode. But running in normal mode the amount of crashes could be reduced by the described improvements.

Comment: But why is the server crashing? Post your logcat with exception and stacktrace. You may need to remove logcat filters to see the problem.