# Howto prevent NotificationListenerService from crashing after clearing app data?

Tags: android, crash, android-service, notification-listener

My question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45124673/notification-listener-service-does-not-work-after-app-is-crashed). But it's a special case. On Android 7 devices the `NotificationListenerService` crashes when I clear app data in app settings and restart the app. But the app does not crash at all. Only the service does not work anymore.

Is this maybe related to the permission for "Notification access" not being requested again? If you delete all app data then you must re-grant all permissions again, except from the "Notification access" permission which is still active til you revoke it manually.

Toggling the service and calling `requestRebind()` [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47964645/2039740) does not rebind the service in that special case (= when clearing the app data).

What can I do? Any small hint will help me alot.

You can find some code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48370088/2039740). It is from a sample app I once built because I cannot post our productive code from here.

I used `adb logcat *:W` and I found this line:

> 05-14 09:15:16.692   863  1731 W ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.xyz.dapp.debug/com.company.subcompany.apppackage.notification.NotificationListener in 1000ms

Comment: Why don't you see the logcat!

Comment: Because it is no app crash. And there is no logcat. Only the service crashes or get's disconnected.

Comment: Try to capture Log Without that it is difficult to suggest anything. Else share show code snippet.

Comment: I linked my other question where you can find my code snippet

Comment: There are no other things within LogCat I can find which are useful. I didn't want to post all 1500 lines

Comment: Finally I posted a "fix" in my [orignal post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48370088/notification-listener-service-not-started-when-running-in-debug-mode)